# Storyboard issues when archiving ios 7 app with ios 6.1 sdk

Tags: ios6, storyboard, ios7

I have re-created my app from scratch using xcode 5 and ios 7. I have set the deployment target to ios 5.0. I am able to run the app successfully on all the ios 5.0+ simulators using xcode 5. And I am able to archive the ios 7.0 version of my app to my iphone without issues.

The issue arises when I try to build by app with the ios 6.1 sdk using xcode 4.6.3. I get the following build error:

```
"The document Main.storyboard could not be opened. Could not read archive."
```

I open that file in source code view, and see this on the top:

```
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="4510" systemVersion="12E55" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" initialViewController="rS3-R9-Ivy">
```

I change the version to 2.0, which is the advice some people are giving. After doing this, I clean and rebuild and get the following error:

```
"The document Main.storyboard could not be opened. Failed to unarchive element named 'tableViewCellContentView'."
```

I am not sure what to do at this point. If it helps, tableViewCellContent shows up two times in the storyboard source:

```
<tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="jxu-2I-e7e" id="p3Z-Dy-Wwr">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="43"/>
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                            <subviews>
                                                <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Share Location" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" id="QHi-wS-Lfa">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="20" y="11" width="116" height="21"/>
                                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                    <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                                                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                </label>
                                                <switch opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="750" verticalHuggingPriority="750" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" on="YES" id="jfR-fE-3PU">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="251" y="6" width="51" height="31"/>
                                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                                    <inset key="insetFor6xAndEarlier" minX="20" minY="-2" maxX="-20" maxY="2"/>
                                                </switch>
                                            </subviews>
                                        </tableViewCellContentView>
```

and

```
<tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="ase-uh-S8O" id="Qfa-Dd-22s">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="43"/>
                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                    <subviews>
                                        <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="left" text="Title" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" id="m8y-pR-Z3V">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="15" y="3" width="36" height="22"/>
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="18"/>
                                            <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                        </label>
                                        <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="left" text="Subtitle" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" id="4bW-Fg-tmx">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="15" y="25" width="43" height="15"/>
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="12"/>
                                            <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                        </label>
                                    </subviews>
                                </tableViewCellContentView>
```

If I remove those two snippets above from the source, I can successfully open the storyboard in xcode 4.6.3 using the ios 6.1 sdk. However, the UI is not correct as a result.

Any ideas what part of this could not be backwards compatible with ios 6.1 sdk?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a storyboard file created/updated using Xcode 5 compatible with Xcode 4.6 by setting the option as below.

[image]

However you will not be able to make iOS 7 related UI changes once you do that.